# how to make mic of android phone work when when the screen is locked

Tags: java, android, ios, speech-to-text, speech

*I made an app that converts speech to text *
:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        checkPermission();

        final EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);

        final SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);


        final Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,
                Locale.getDefault());


        
        })
    }


    private void checkPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                        Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used recogniser intent for speech to text conversion.
here I couldn't find how to make my mic work once the screen is locked ....can provide me with a solution?

Comment: I don't think you would access mic while the phone is locked . cause if u can do this ,this means the phone will never goto sleep, the battery will run out fast.

Comment: in specific for an application can we do it as it can take our voice as input even when the screen is locked?

Comment: Of cause we can , like music , maybe you should hold a **wakelock** to do this.